# RDDs and SPARK Streaming Microbatches

Tags: apache-spark, streaming

Can we expect 1 RDD per microbatch always? Or is this dependent on number of receivers? How can we guarantee sorting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- A single microbatch is always one RDD. It doesn't depend on the number of receivers.
- To ensure specific batch ordering you can use `stream.transform(_.someMethodThatSortsRDD)`.

Comment: What if there is a hiccup and delay? On next invocation could there not be 2 RDDS?

Comment: It won't happen. Batches are always processed in order. If one is still in process no other batch from the same stream will start.